# Magento 2 Get all attributes option in phtml

Tags: attributes, magento-2.2.5

I have created an attribute with multiple options I have to get all option of in dropdown.

Attribute created: country
Options: India, USA, UK

below is my code in phmtl file

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $productCollection->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('country')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('country', array('notnull' => true))// get only not null values
        ->getSelect()->group('country');
print_r($collection);
```

it does not show all attribute option of the country.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 3):

The code which you have used only give those options which are selected on all products.'

You want to all option of a product attribute then you have to use below code:

**Using OBject Manager:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'country');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

**Using Injection**

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ...
}

public function getAllOption()
{
    attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'country');
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**By Factory Method :**

You need to inject `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` in your construct

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ...
}
```

then you can use that in your class

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'country');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

**By Object Manager :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'country');

$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(); // for attribute option.
```

**Note : Don't use object manager direct.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $col = $_objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory');
    $cole = $_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory');
    
    $attributeSetId = 4; //Here is attribute set id
    $groupIds = [];
    $attributeids = [];
    $somearray=[];
        $groupCollection = $col->create()
        ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
        ->load(); // product attribute group collection
    foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
        
        $groupAttributesCollection = $cole->create()
            ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
            ->addVisibleFilter()
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined', array('eq' => 1))
                ->load(); // product attribute collection
       
        foreach ($groupAttributesCollection->getItems() as $attribute) {
            
            $opte=$attribute->getname();
            //echo "<strong>".$opte."</strong>";
            $opt=$attribute->getid();
            $options=$block->getattributeoptions($opt);
    
                  foreach($options as $values){
                  // echo $values['label'];
                }
        }
    }
```